# How can $\int_{t}^{t+T}xx^Td\tau \geq \alpha_1 I$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, especially when the determinant of outer product or $xx^T$ is 0?

Tags: vectors, outer-product, adaptive-control

I am quite perplexed, I wish to prove one of the fundamental lemmas in adaptive control, i.e., 
\begin{equation}
\alpha_1 I \leq \int_t^{t+T}xx^Td\tau \leq \alpha_2 I
\end{equation}
where, $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,T$ are positive constants and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Now, how is this possible when we know that $xx^T$ is the outer product which has determinant 0? Please shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that at every time instance the matrix $x\,x^\top$ is singular (it can even at most only have rank one). However, an integral can be seen as a summation and summing multiple singular matrices can become a nonsingular matrix. For example the two by two identity matrix can be written as

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}^\top + 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}^\top.
$$

Comment: Hi! so for  a $n\times n$ matrix resulting as an outer product of $n$ dimensional vector, you need to sum it at least $n$ times to arrive at a matrix that is full rank?

Comment: @Amardeepmishra Yes and the integral can be seen as an infinite sum (for example by taking the limit of the Riemann sum). But $x$ does need to vary enough in the given time window (it needs to have persistence excitation).

Comment: Thats what i had in my mind as well, I was thinking more like, there should be at least, $n$ independent vectors whose outer products needs to be summed up to create a full rank PD matrix. Right?

Comment: Is my assessment correct?

Comment: Also, by summing it n times, we'll end up getting, a matrix that is full tank, but what's the guarantee that it'll be positive definite?

Comment: @dead_space every $x\,x^\top$ is a positive semi-definite matrix (PSDM) and the sum of a PSDM with another PSDM is either also a PSDM or a positive definite matrix. Also a PSDM is not full rank, but a positive definite matrix is. Thus if the integral is full rank it should also be positive definite.